# UICollection View never loads

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I have made a UICollection View. In my ViewController I have the following code:

```
import UIKit
import AlamofireImage

class MYViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, MYItemCellDelegate {

    let viewModel : MYViewModel = StandPlaceViewModel()

    @IBOutlet weak var itemCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ItemCountLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.viewModel.getItems(self.viewModel.stand) { items in
            self.ItemCountLabel.text = String(self.viewModel.itemCount)
            self.itemCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.viewModel.tableDict.count
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("IN COLLECTION OF ITEMS")
        let cell: MYItemCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("itemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MYItemCell
        cell.itemTitleLabel.text = self.viewModel.tableDict[indexPath.row]![0]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }

...
```

My Issue is that the UICollection never loads. IN COLLECTION OF ITEMS is never printed. I have a separate page with a collection and it all works just fine and I cant find the difference.

The `ItemCountLabel.text` is properly set in the viewDidLoad(), but the reloadData() never seems to call the collectionView code.

I would expect IN COLLECTION OF ITEMS to be printed twice.

Comment: Did you try adding `self.itemCollectionView.dataSource = self` in the beginning of viewDidLoad()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these code into `viewDidLoad`

```
self.itemCollectionView.delegate = self;
self.itemCollectionView.dataSource = self;
```